# How to re-write script of matrix 3D matlab in python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I newbie in python. I have matlab script like below. I want to re-write matrix 3D in matlab script in to python 3.x language. How can I fix it?

```
nl=length(res);
ndat=length(per);
phi=atan(1)*4;
amu=phi*4e-7;

for i=1:ndat
  for j=1:nl
     z=sqrt(phi*amu*res(j)/per(i));
     zz(j)=complex(z,z);
     exp0=exp((-2)*zz(j)/res(j)*thi(j));
     exp1=complex(1,0)+exp0;
     exp2=complex(1,0)-exp0;

     %matrix 3D
     ldi(1,1,j)=exp1;
     ldi(1,2,j)=zz(j)*exp2
     ldi(2,1,j)=exp2/zz(j);
     ldi(2,2,j)=exp1;`
  end
end
```

Comment: Take a look at `numpy` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find a self-contained implementation of your code (below), with a few key differences:

1. Python indexing starts from 0 instead of one
2. Python indexing uses square brackets instead of round ones
3. Mathematic functions must be imported from libraries (here *math* and *cmath*)

Good luck!

```
import math
import cmath

# Data
res = [1, 4, 1, 2, 3]
per = [5, 5, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.6]
thi = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
nl = len(res)
ldi = [[[0 for x in range(nl)],[0 for x in range(nl)]], [[0 for x in range(nl)],[0 for x in range(nl)]]]
zz = [0]*nl


nl = len(res)
ndat = len(per)
phi = math.atan(1)*4
amu = phi*4e-7

for i in range(ndat):
  for j in range(nl):
    z = math.sqrt(phi*amu*res[j]/per[i])
    zz[j] = complex(z,z)
    exp0=cmath.exp((-2)*zz[j]/res[j]*thi[j]);
    exp1=complex(1,0)+exp0;
    exp2=complex(1,0)-exp0;

    #- matrix 3D
    ldi[0][0][j]=exp1;
    ldi[0][1][j]=zz[j]*exp2
    ldi[1][0][j]=exp2/zz[j]
    ldi[1][1][j]=exp1
```

Comment: It's interesting to see how it looks in plain python but you really should use numpy when translating from matlab.

Comment: @EricDuminil. I agree. I kept it at OP's level since they seem to be complete beginner in Python.